# Bootstrap template appears full length

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Any bootstrap Login or registration template that i copy the codes into a JSP file and try to run, the form is wide screen. I can't seem to figure out why. I use the same code in the template. This is how it looks like :

[image]

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link class="cssdeck" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" class="cssdeck">

<div class="" id="loginModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Have an Account?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="well">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Create Account</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action='' method="POST">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div id="legend">
                                <legend class="">Login</legend>
                            </div>    
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Username -->
                                <label class="control-label"  for="username">Username</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Password-->
                                <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Button -->
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>                
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
                    <form id="tab">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <textarea value="Smith" rows="3" class="input-xlarge">
                        </textarea>

                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your code inside `<div class="container">`